How to deploy Elastic Beanstalk?

I'm trying to deploy a backend file using Express + typescript + prisma via Elastic beanstalk.
I tried various methods recommended in the official documentation.

I did a lot of searching and spent 4 days on it.
I think it might be related to package.json.
This is an error message that keeps occurring.
Node.js v20.12.2

backend@1.0.0 start
node build/app.js
/var/app/current/node_modules/.prisma/client/default.js:43
throw new Error(
^
Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://pris.ly/prisma-prisma-bug-report
at new PrismaClient (/var/app/current/node_modules/.prisma/client/default.js:43:11)
at Object. (/var/app/current/build/lib/prisma.js:4:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
at Object. (/var/app/current/build/controllers/post.js:54:32)

This is a GitHub link to the code file I am trying to distribute.
Github
Package.json Code
    {
      "name": "backend",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "npm run generate && tsc --project tsconfig.build.json",
        "start": "node build/app.js",
        "dev": "nodemon app.ts",
        "generate": "npx prisma generate"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.569.0",
        "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.569.0",
        "@prisma/client": "^5.13.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "express": "^4.19.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
        "prisma": "^5.13.0",
        "sharp": "^0.33.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
        "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.7",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
        "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
        "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
        "typescript": "^5.4.5"
      }
    }

Here are the methods I tried and the link to the document.

Add the prisma CLI package to your dependencies instead of the devDependencies. (Making sure to run npm install afterward to update the package-lock.json).
Or install your devDependencies on AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances. To do this you must set the AWS Elastic Beanstalk NPM_USE_PRODUCTION environment property to false.

3.you need to create an .npmrc file in the root of your project and add the following configuration.
official document
